# Oracle : Flow to call the subroutines

Tags: database, oracle

Consider there are 4 jobs **A,B,C** and **MAIN**.The MAIN Job will call other subroutines based on the some condition.The **Main Job** will call the **Job A** on the first business day of the every week.also it will call **JOB B** on every business day.Also it will call the **Job C** on the first day of the every month. Can anyone suggest me the flow to do it?

I am using oracle 10g.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you are going to be using oracle.. you can set up main to query the database..where you set the schedules (name of the stored proc and the schedule format)..the format of the schedule can something similar to what is used in crontab, but something less powerful should be sufficient for you i guess...

**updated answer**

Following is the table you need to create.
StoredProcName, timeToRun
1) ProcA             FirstDayOfBusiness
2) ProcB             Every business day 
3) ProcC             FirstDay of EveryMonth.

Your Main will have logic to get all jobs from this table and decide if they need to be run and then run them if needed, Is any sequence also important.. or the jobs are independent of previous job runs?

**read this**
http://www.orafaq.com/node/871

Comment: Following is a table you create.

Comment: http://adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference for how crontab uses a format to know when the job is to be run(Ex every first monday of every second month...etc)

Comment: @Mahesh: thanks.Just now got an idea from your answer.Is there any example store procedure for the same available in the web?if so,Plz let me know

Comment: read this http://www.orafaq.com/node/871 .also dont forget to mark this as an answer if it has helped.

Comment: @Mahesh: till now i didnt receive any answer from others.I ll accept ur answer if it is correct.now i am searching for the sample table structures ,the pseuodocode for Main Job and all.

Comment: @mahesh: Can u please share the sample table structure and the flow of calling the store procedure inside my main job as per ur assumption?